# Update array but retain existing array in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How do I update first item of time using map?

```
const myArr = [{
  day: 1,
  time: [1200, 1400]
}]

newTime = 1300;
myNewArr = myArr.map(d => {
  return {
    day: d.day,
    time: [newTime] // but this don't care about order
  }
})
console.log(myNewArr)
```

which is 1200, replace it with says 1300, but keep 1400 as the second item? or vice versa replace 1400 with another number.

Comment: Why don't you do it directly with `myArr[0].time[0] = 1300`?

Comment: Use `spread` operator instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and take an object with the wanted index for replacement.

```js
var myArr = [{ day: 1, time: [1200, 1400] }],
    newTime = 1300,
    myNewArr = myArr.map(
        ({ day, time }) => ({ day, time: Object.assign([], time, { 0: newTime }) })
    );

console.log(myNewArr);
```

Comment: wow didn't know it can take index like that, I can't do this with spread operator right?

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you don't want to update the original array, you could use slice with `spread syntax` to update the data like

```js
const myArr = [{
  day: 1,
  time: [1200, 1400]
}]

newTime = 1300;
myNewArr = myArr.map(d => {
  return {
    day: d.day,
    time: [newTime, ...d.time.slice(1)]
  }
})
console.log(myNewArr)
```

Please note that mapping over your data and updating like above will update the entire list of objects.

You could use `Object.assign` instead of spread syntax as @NinaScholz also suggested, That way you can update any particular index. It comes from the fact that array accepts integer indices

```js
const myArr = [{
  day: 1,
  time: [1200, 1400]
}]

newTime = 1300;
myNewArr = myArr.map(d => {
  return {
    day: d.day,
    time: Object.assign([], time, {1: newTime})
  }
})
console.log(myNewArr)
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry wrong choice of words from my part

Comment: do I have to change anything in this line `time: [newTime, ...d.time.slice(1)]` if I want to update the second array instead of the first one?

Comment: yes , `time: [...d.time.slice(0, index), newTime, ...d.time.slice(index + 1)]` where index is the index that you want to update, this syntax will work with index 0 as well

Comment: Just FWIW, *"...It comes from the fact that array accepts integer indices..."* Really it comes from the fact that standard arrays are just objects. There's nothing special about `assign` re arrays, it's just that assign's logic works on objects and arrays are objects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I am just really bad at explaining. What I mean was {1: newTime} when used with Object.assign([],  {1: newTime} ) will internally treat it like `a=[], a[1] = newTime`

Comment: You're not really bad at explaining. :-) If you were, I wouldn't bother to comment.

Comment: you have a typo at line `Object.assign([], time, {1: newTime}]`

Comment: @SharonChai: Not as readable, and less efficient. But for the index-0 case in your question, spread would be nice and readable (but still less efficient than Nina's `assign` because of the temporary array).

Comment: Well, efficiency is rarely all that important. You have to be dealing with a massive array, or doing the operation a lot. :-)